# Installation Error : Sitecore 9.1.0

Tags: installation, powershell

I am installing Install `Sitecore 9.1.0` using `PowerShell` script and getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to target server. Please verify the connection
> information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall
> rules for the target server.

[image]

Although I already verified SQL server credentials that didn't help.

Comment: Can you verify your SQL Server version?

Comment: How have you verified the SQL connection? Is it possible malformed connection string? Have you confirmed correct port is open and it is correctly in conn string?

Comment: I saw that in the compatibility table it's the same as required.

Comment: you need to specify the SQL Server Name in the config. You can get it by logging into your SQL Server instance

Comment: In your snapshot, it says that 'network path was not found'. That should be your starting point to fix it. I also think that SQL server may not have remote access enabled which can be done by running following query - EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 0;
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

Comment: The line in the install script where the connection string is ultimately formed needs to be adjusted. I have seen numerous examples / tutorials in which that line requires adjusting. Also, make sure you can actually log into SQL via SSMS and that you can see the tables in there. If not, you likely haven't completed all of the necessary SQL installations.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of `Sitecore 9.1.0` requires `Sitecore Installation Framework version 2.0.0`. See this table for more info:

| Sitecore | Sitecore Installation Framework |
| --- | --- |
| 9.0.x | 1.2.1 |
| 9.1 | 2.0.0 |
| 9.1.1 | 2.1.0 or later |
| 9.2.0 | 2.1.0 or later |
| 9.3.0 | 2.2.0 |
| 10.0.0 | 2.3.0 |

It seems you're currently using version `2.3.0` based on the error message. So you should first install the correct version.

Install a specific version of SIF

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion x.x.x
```

Use a particular version of SIF for installation - this is important when installing

```
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Force -RequiredVersion x.x.x
```

This info is based on this blog: https://kezhan.info/2020/09/10/Sitecore-Installation-Framework-and-Sitecore-Versions-Compatibility-Table